# ERROR: No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined'

Tags: angular, ng-modules, lazy-loading

I have transpiled one angular module. Or 2nd case i have one angular module JS file to load into another Angular app using lazy loading. But got this error No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined'.

Tried multiple solutions of reinstalling node_modules and updating the code.

I believe the file i am importing is not having angular angular code in it, so causing the problem.

Anyone can help or let me know the way to load angular module which is placed outside the angular folder(or another angular app)

Comment: can you tell which module you are adding, or show little bit of your code, where you think the problem is coming, so that we can help you etter

Comment: its custom module. Simple module lets say with hello world written in it. I have exported it using tsc compiler into JS file, which is in another angular project. And i wanted to load that file into 2nd project as loadChildren(lazy load)

Comment: using this to load another module
https://github.com/kirjs/angular-dynamic-module-loading

Comment: I am only taing single JS file which consist of app code without angular core and other stuff, because it is already loaded in 2nd project. I just want to load module.

Comment: Can you post some sample code or create a stackblitz. It will help to understand the problem better.